# Ant not rebuilding newer source?

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to figure out what might be causing Ant to fail to rebuild a dependency that has newer source.

I have several packages, each with their own build target in Ant.  One of the targets, mds, depends on another target, robotsim.  If I fail to add that in the list of dependencies I get crazy behavior, it only builds sometimes and I'd like to learn when and why.

```
$ ant clean mds
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

At this point I open up a java file in the robotsim package and delete a semicolon.

```
$ ls -l src/com/robotsim/model/Robot.java 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 matt matt 6.3K 2012-05-15 14:28 src/com/robotsim/model/Robot.java
$ ls -l build/com/robotsim/model/Robot.class 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 matt matt 6.6K 2012-05-15 14:13 build/com/robotsim/model/Robot.class
$ ant mds
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ ant clean mds
...
[javac] Robot.java:110: ';' expected
...
BUILD FAILED
```

So the question is, why is the second build successful?

Edit to include relevant parts of build.xml:

```
<target name='init'>
    <mkdir dir='${build.dir}'/>
    <mkdir dir='${dist.dir}'/>
</target>
...
<target name='customTasks'>
    <javac srcdir='${customTasks.src.dir}' destdir='${ant.library.dir}' classpathref='customTasks.classpath' failonerror='false'/>
    <taskdef name='protoc' classname='com.hrilab.Protoc' classpath="${ant.library.dir}"/>
</target>
...
<target name='algorithms' depends='init' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds a few generic algorithms'>
    <build-java package.dir='com/algorithms'/>
</target>
...
<target name='engine3d' depends='init' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds the 3D engine'>
    <build-java package.dir='com/engine3D'/>
</target>
...
<target name='humanoid' depends='init,utilities' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds the humanoid servers.'>
    <build-java package.dir='com/humanoid'/>
</target>
...
<target name='mds' depends='init,algorithms,engine3d,humanoid' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds the servers for the Xitome MDS.'>
    <build-java package.dir='com/mds'/>
</target>
...
<target name='robotsim' depends='init,customTasks' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds the 3D robot simulator'>
    <protoc minversion='2.4.0' srcfile='com/robotsim/calibration/leng/calibration_server_config.proto' destdir='${src.dir}'/>
    <protoc minversion='2.4.0' srcfile='com/robotsim/calibration/leng/extrinsic_parameters_collection.proto' destdir='${src.dir}'/>
    <build-java package.dir='com/robotsim'/>
</target>
...
<target name='utilities' depends='init' extensionOf='compile' description='Builds some common utilities'>
    <build-java package.dir='utilities'/>
</target>
...
<macrodef name='build-java'>
    <attribute name='classpath' default='base.classpath'/>
    <attribute name='package.dir' default='NOT SET'/>
    <attribute name='package.mask' default='**'/> <!-- HACK: please do not use this attribute, it's only here to hack around the way we have our source laid out -->
    <sequential>
        <javac srcdir='${src.dir}' destdir='${build.dir}' includes='@{package.dir}/@{package.mask}' debug='${debug.enabled}' debuglevel='${debug.level}'>
            <classpath refid='@{classpath}'/>
        </javac>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: It would help to see your `build.xml`; the first target seems to succeed based on the existence of the `class` files, whereas `clean mds` fails because the class files are gone and must be recompiled...

Comment: More detail added.  The thing that gets me is that it says in the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) that newer java files should be rebuilt, but that doesn't seem to always be the case.

Comment: Hrm, I think we'll need all the `depends` attributes at least to see the intended chain of events... e.g. for `algorithms`, `engine3d`. Probably not the actual contents of those targets, though. Also, have you tried raising the ant log level to see what it thinks it should be doing?

Comment: Per your suggestion I'm pouring through the -debug output for the first two cases, but I'm not 100% on what I should be looking for.  I grepped both for 'Robot' and didn't get any useful hits.  It looks like the reason the second one succeeded was that Robot.java never had javac called on it at all.  Which means the question is why did it build the first time?

Comment: My guess is that this happens because the `com/robotsim/` directory will be built in the `robotsim` target. And since `mds` and `robotsim` are siblings of a sort (in that they both extend `compile`) and since `mds` doesn't explicitly depend on `robotsim`, these class files were left in place. If you had changed something in `com/mds/` instead, it probably would have been recompiled. Or if you had executed `clean compile` or `clean dist` or something similar.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, how does `compile` do this?  My understanding is that extension-points don't do anything unless you call them, am I missing something huge?

Comment: Eh, I might be wrong about using `compile`, but if you run a target that depends on compile (e.g. if you have a `dist` or `package` target), all of the targets which extend compile should be executed before that target.

Comment: Ping!  Is there anything else I can add that might make this an easier question to answer?

Comment: Have you tried running `ant clean robotsim mds`? As I wrote previously, the error you've introduced is for a class which is built in your `robotsim` target, so just running `ant mds` isn't going to recompile that class file and therefore not complain about the syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, I can compile, that's not the issue, I'm trying to figure out why it behaves the way it does, why it will build unspecified dependencies, but it won't rebuild them.